# create front-end users post list by specific category

Tags: php, posts, users, front-end, id

I am trying to create a post list that will show current users posts by specific category and show the post id inside the title. So, I wrote the code below, but it isn't working work. Any suggestions please:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array( 2 ),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'author' => $user_id
);                       
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php get_the_ID(); ?></a> 
<?php           
    endwhile;

else :

    echo "not logged in";

endif;

?>
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? If everything except the ID is showing, try `echo get_the_ID();` instead of just `get_the_ID();`.

Comment: @WebElaine Working good but show all post not the specific category please check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no arguments array key name `'post_category'` in WP_Query . Insted of `'post_category'` use either `'category__in' => array( 2, 6 )` or `category_name' => 'staff'`.

And also for the id case use `echo get_the_ID()` ... to print the post id

Comment: Helpful source: https://gist.github.com/luetkemj/2023628